# Show results for a given month, SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with orders in it in SQL, I need to show all of the orders for any given month, say it was this month, May.

At the moment all I have is:

```
select o.OrderNo, convert(varchar,o.OrderDate,103)
from Order o
Order by o.OrderNo
```

This is probably pretty straight forward but my mind is blank at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MONTH function

```
WHERE MONTH(OrderDate) = 5  AND YEAR(OrderDate) = 2014
```

Comment: @Mihal Thanks for the answer, I had a feeling it was something straight forward, thanks for the edit to btw, I'm new to the site and need to learn to format my code when posting it

Comment: just make sure u add the year, otherwise it will give results for ALL the Mays in your table :-D